# Is using multiple subscriptions fine?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I wonder whether It's fine strategy to using multiple subscriptions for each components. So I'm confuse to choose which of the patterns below. I'm using GraphQL's subscriptions with redis's Pub/Sub.

If you know about relate informations or posts, let me know. Thanks for reading. :D

#### Case 1

```
Subscription Set_item {
    set_item {
        name
        no
    }
}

class Items extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount () {
        apolloClient
            .subscribe({ query:Set_item })
            .subscribe({ data } => {
                const item = this.props.items.find((item) => item.no === data.set_item.no);

                if (data.set_item.name !== item.name)
                    this.props.set_item(data.set_item.no, { name:data.set_item.name });
            });
    }

    render () {
        return this.props.items.map((item) => <Item item={item} key={item.no}/>);
    }
}

class Item extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div>{this.props.item.name}</div>;
    }
}
```

#### Case 2

```
Subscription Set_item ($no:Int) {
    set_item (no:$no) {
        name
    }
}

class Items extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return this.props.items.map((item) => <Item item={item} key={item.no}/>);
    }
}

class Item extends React.Component {
    componentdidMount () {
        apolloClient
            .subscribe({ query:Set_item, variables:{ no:this.props.item.no} })
            .subscribe({ data } => {
                if (data.set_item.name !== this.props.item.name)
                    this.props.set_item(this.props.item.no, { name:data.set_item.name });
            })
    }

    render () {
        return <div>{this.props.item.name}</div>;
    }
}
```